# Element transforms when active (half click)

Tags: html, css

I was following a Youtube tutorial to create a Memory Card game. Halfway through I started to tinker to see if I could figure out the steps myself. I have a div that looks like this:

```
<div class="memory-card">
        <img class="front-face" src="img/aurelia.svg" alt="Aurelia">
        <img class="back-face" src="img/js-badge.svg" alt="JSBadge">
</div>
```

The CSS for this div looks like this

```
.memory-card {
    width: calc(25% - 10px);
    height: calc(33.33% - 10px); 
    position: relative;
    margin: 5px;
    transition: transform 0.2s;
}

.memory-card:active {
    transform: scale(0.97);
    transition: transform 0.2s;
}

.flip {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transition: transform 0.2s;
}
```

The class "flip" is added to the div by toggling on the classList of the memory-card element when a click occurs. Essentially what this does is that when the memory-card is clicked and held it becomes active and scales to 0.97 and when released it is rotated by 180 degrees around the Y-axis (class="memory-card flip").

Before click

[image: Before click]

[image: After click]

However, when I click again (and hold) it rotates again without waiting for the click to be released. As per my understanding (which has a hole that I hope you can fill), the card (which the div represents btw) should rotate only after I release the click. Can anybody help? This seems like an issue that must have been answered before but for the life of me, I could not find it.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the edit. It looks much better. Could you tell me how you did that just for reference?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```js
var memorycard = document.querySelector('.memory-card');

memorycard.onclick = function(e) {
   memorycard.classList.toggle('flip');
};
```

```css
.memory-card {
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
  height: calc(33.33% - 10px);
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}

.memory-card:active {
  transform: scale(0.97);
}

.memory-card.flip:active {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(0.97);
}

.flip {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

img {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="memory-card">
  <img class="front-face" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/esMJU.png" alt="Aurelia">
  <img class="back-face" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xR2ZZ.png" alt="JSBadge">
</div>
```

`.flip` has this CSS property: `transform: rotateY(180deg);`. However, as soon as the click begins, `.memory-card:active` is applied, so that property gets overwritten as `transform: scale(0.97);`. The solution is to specify that when the `.flip` class is present, both transform functions should be applied:

```css
.memory-card.flip:active {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(0.97);
}
```

Comment: That worked. I have a questions:
So if I understand it correctly as soon as we begin to click "memory-card flip" the .memory-card:active transform is applied (which is desirable). Why doesn't the .memory-card.flip:active transform take effect (which would actually both rotate and scale the element as we begin the click (which is undesirable))?

Comment: It's totally desirable and it does take effect when `.memory-card` has class `.flip` as soon as the click begins. Try removing that, you will see that the problem comes back. When the `.flip` class is present, `rotateY` keeps it flipped and `scale` adds the click effect until the click is released (because at that point, the `.flip` class gets removed).